# java jersey exception interceptor

Tags: java, rest, exception, jersey

I have the following Jersey endpoint:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/sessionlog")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getSessionLog(@HeaderParam(CLIENT_HEADER_PARAM) String clientId,
                                  @QueryParam("sessionId") Long sessionId,
                                  @QueryParam("callback") String callback) {
}
```

And I want to create a handler that intercepts any exception that may occur inside this endpoint and all other endpoints over the application. I don't want to throw anything, wrap code in try...catch, I just want this handler to accept any exception and, ideally, respond with special response. How to achieve that?

I tried this

```
@Provider
public class  RestExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Exception> {

    public Response toResponse(Exception exception){

        return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).
                entity(new ErrorResponse(exception.getClass().toString(),
                        exception.getMessage()) ).
                build();
    }
}
```

But I want to create just try..catch...throw free code in my endpoints. Thanks

Comment: `I don't want to throw anything, wrap code in try...catch, I just want this handler to accept any exception`: what does it mean? And how should the code know that there was a problem if you don't tell it (by throwing an exception)?

Comment: I believe that Jersey uses AOP to intercept calls, why can't it detect unchecked exception and throw it? Thanks

Comment: If you throw `WebApplicationException` in your code Jersey will handle it automatically, but if you don't want to throw it?

Comment: The idea was to catch for example division by zero exception, NPE, etc. Thanks